# Angular4 : ngFor with variable or number: Is it planned in the future?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I would like to know, if Angular team have planned to add a number or variable for ngfor? It will be really comfortable for development.

Currently, we have to create a fake table

`fakeArray = new Array(12);`
and then 
`<li *ngFor="let a of fakeArray"></li>`

Thank you community.

Comment: This is a really broad question.... when you iterate how else would you loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic explanation for *NgFor

NgFor is a directive that iterates over a collection of data. It is used to customize data display. Whenever there is change in collection of data at runtime, that will be updated in data display iterated by NgFor directive. NgFor provides local variables that will help to get index of current iteration, detect if an element in iteration is first or last and odd or even. NgFor is used with HTML element as well as component element. NgFor with HTML element iterates the template within it. NgFor with component element iterates the child component HTML template. NgFor can be used with asterisk(*) or template directive or template tag. Any change in contents in iteration is propagated to DOM.

the question you asked is really broad and will be not useful for using *ngFor. hence they can make new directive for assigning a variable in future but that will be using in a very rare case.

Comment: <li *ngFor="let a of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15].slice(0,15-number)"></li>